# Using SED to move a value after equals to a matching file

Tags: xml, regex, perl, sed

I have tried multiple things when moving the keystorePass value from one `server.xml` to another. I am not very good with `sed` but have tried multiple things including using patterns, i also used grep to take that specific line with the keystore password to a blank file and move the line to the new `server.xml` but that did not work either. Everyone probably already knows what the `server.xml` usually contains but here is an example of the section I need fixed.

**

```
keystoreFile="/etc/blank"
keystorePass="BLAH" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

**

Now when we deliver a build we have our own set of `server.xml` which only works with our servers but when our users deploy it they use a different keystorePass. I was just having it to where the file is moved back over once the build is finished but we sometimes need to make some edits to the file so it must be replaced.

All in all I need the password after `keystorePass=` in `server.xml1` to replace the one in `server.xml2`

```
server.xml1 (Test)
keystoreFile="/etc/blank/"
keystorePass="BadPassword" sslProtocol = "TLS" />


server.xml2 (Customer)
keystoreFile="/etc/blank/"
keystorePass="GoodPassword" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

Comment: Could you please post the `sed` commands that you have tried?

Comment: I used grep to get the pattern for the keystore pass line and put it in a test.xml file. Then using sed i cant seem to get just after the equals including the "". I used the following and got just keystorePass. sed 's/.*=//' test.xml. Problem after that is how do i get that output to the other server.xml to replace that password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read your question is that you want to copy the "BadPassword" from `server.xml1` to the "GoodPassword" in `server.xml2`. If so, then use this short script:

```
#!/bin/bash
password=`grep keystorePass= old.xml | awk -F\" '{print $2'}` 
cat old.xml | sed 's/@PASSWORD@/$password/' > server.xml.bak
mv server.xml.bak server.xml
```

This will write whatever the string between [`keystorePass="`] and the following [`"`] from `server.xml1` to `server.xml2`.

NOTE: This assumes that the password can be any character except a quote (`[^"]`). Also, once you save the script make sure you run `chmod +x script_name.sh` and then use `./script_name.sh` to run the script.

I would create a file dummy files to test the script on before trying it on the real thing. Let me know if I misinterpreted your question.

You can also try the shorter version below.
**WARNING**: It may have some issues depending on your version of `bash`

```
#!/binbash
passwd=$(sed -nr 's/keystorePass="([^"]*).*/\1/p' server.xml1)
sed -i.xml -r "s/(keystorePass=\")[^\"]*(.*)/\1"$passwd"\2/" server.xml2
```

Comment: Why not just use a `[^"]` for the character class so you don't have to worry about enumerating the characters that can appear in it: you know it cannot possibly contain a double-quote, since that's what terminates the attribute value.

Comment: If they're not, it's going to be problematical either way.

Comment: Whenever I run the script above using two test xml files, new.xml old.xml it comes back with the following error."sed: -e expression #1, char 33: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS". Also it will clear out the entire new.xml file. I think it may be since the test password we use has a special character and maybe that is throwing it off. I can play around with it to see if i can get it working. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @Brian I believe I've fixed the issue. The problem was that I didn't supply `sed -i` with a file extension so it didn't create a backup file. This should work with your `.xml` files, but always do a test run to make sure. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: @skamazin it's no longer removing the contents of the file but now it will not replace the password in the new.xml but leave it blank it will look like this -keystorePass="" with just the quotes.

Comment: Do me a favor and run this line and tell me what the output is
`awk -F\" '{ if($1 == "keystorePass=") { print $2} }' server.xml1`

Comment: There is no output for that commmand. There isnt an error either

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `server.xml1` looks like what you posted in your question? Character by character the exact same thing, down to the quotation marks?

Comment: There is more content in the server.xml1 but the area i showed you is exact i just copied and pasted it. I changed it to a generic passwords, here is what i have for that section. keystorePass="@WSX!qaz" sslProtocol = "TLS" /> . Also when i run the script above it is creating a server.xml2.xml

Comment: When run the `awk` command it correctly returns `@WSX!qaz`. Hmm... can you run `awk --version` and tell me what version you're running?

Comment: I am running GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: Alright, I edited the answer, go ahead and try again on a dummy file

Comment: Roger that it may be something with the awk command. If i run that at prompt i get nothing same if i run it through the script. The sed command does something but it will only remove the password out of the new server.xml file. Its like since it doesn't receive the new password its making it blank.

Comment: got the following. sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Did you trying running the first `sed` in command-line instead of in the script?

Comment: Nice yeah that will output the password.

Comment: Then run the second `sed` but replace `$passwd` with the output of the first `sed`. Meaning manually type the output of the first `sed` into the second `sed` and then `cat server.xml2` and tell me what you get.

Comment: ok so it doesnt like something with the special characters in the password i get the following. 
-bash: !qaz'\2/': event not found

Comment: so you typed `@WSX!qaz` in for `$passwd`. Try escaping the `@` (as in `\@WSX!qaz`)

Comment: I typed this and got the same error, it doesnt like where it starts with !.  sed -i.xml -r 's/(keystorePass=")[^"]*(.*)/\1'\@WSX!qaz'\2/' new.xml

Comment: Make sure you remove the single quotes (`'`) around `@WSX!qaz`. Sorry I forget to mention that. So the command should be `sed -i.xml -r 's/(keystorePass=")[^"]*(.*)/\1@WSX!qaz\2/' new.xml`

Comment: That works perfect now. So what is causing it now to work in the script?

Comment: It might be due to the expansion on the single quotes. Try my answer again (I switched it to double quotes)

Comment: this error came up.sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command

Comment: I honestly don't know then. You're running this on a GNU/Linux Terminal, right?

Comment: Yes i am, i tried removing the $passwd in the script and put in a random password and that works in the script. So it doesn't recognize something with that variable and it also creates another server.xml and called server.xml.xml

Comment: The `server.xml.xml` is a back-up of the original `server.xml` so you can probably `rm` that file within the script. But it's still odd how `passwd` isn't getting assigned correctly. What version of `bash` are you running and on what GNU distro?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Almost the same as mine. Try adding `echo $passwd` between the two lines in the script

Comment: We were able to get it working using the following. You can test it out, please add this to you above script and I can mark you up. You have been extremely helpful and I cant believe you stuck with me that long lol. Thanks again `password=`grep keystorePass= old.xml | awk -F\" '{print $2'}`
cat old.xml | sed s/@PASSWORD@/$password/ > server.xml.bak
mv server.xml.bak server.xml